# Apply a text to the first item with a specific class name in all the li's

Tags: javascript

I'm having an unordered list with multiple items, for which I have to apply a text only to the first item with class `status`.

Currently, the way I tried to do it, replaces the text to all items having the class `status`.

How should I write the loop to change the text only to the first found item with class status (example: text under Name 1 and text under Name 4 from the snippet below).

```js
var str = document.querySelectorAll(".second-level > .status");
    for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        str[i].textContent  = "TEST ME";
    }
```

```css
.name {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
.status {
  color: red;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="second-level" style="display: block;">
        <div class="name">Name 1</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
        
        <div class="name">Name 2</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country"></div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>



        <div class="name">Name 3</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>
        <div class="country"></div>
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
      </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="second-level" style="display: block;">
        <div class="name">Name 4</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
        
        <div class="name">Name 5</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country"></div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop to do something once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `querySelector`. It returns the first element that matches the specified selector.

```js
for (let el of document.querySelectorAll(".second-level")) {
  el = el.querySelector(".status");
  if (el != null) el.textContent = "TEST ME";
}
```

```css
.name {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
.status {
  color: red;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="second-level" style="display: block;">
        <div class="name">Name 1</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
        
        <div class="name">Name 2</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country"></div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>



        <div class="name">Name 3</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>
        <div class="country"></div>
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
      </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="second-level" style="display: block;">
        <div class="name">Name 4</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
        
        <div class="name">Name 5</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country"></div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the first child with class `.status` will occur within the first M children you can use `var str = document.querySelectorAll(".second-level .status:nth-child(-n+M)");`. see: [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

For example in the snippet below:

```
var str = document.querySelectorAll(".second-level .status:nth-child(-n+3)");
```

```js
var str = document.querySelectorAll(".second-level .status:nth-child(-n+3)");
    for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        str[i].textContent  = "TEST ME";
    }
```

```css
.name {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
.status {
  color: red;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="second-level" style="display: block;">
        <div class="name">Name 1</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
        
        <div class="name">Name 2</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country"></div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>

        <div class="name">Name 3</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>
        <div class="country"></div>
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
      </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="second-level" style="display: block;">
        <div class="name">Name 4</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
        
        <div class="name">Name 5</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country"></div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".second-level > .status");

if (nodes.length) {
  nodes[0].textContent  = "TEST ME";
}
```

```css
.name {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
.status {
  color: red;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="second-level" style="display: block;">
        <div class="name">Name 1</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
        
        <div class="name">Name 2</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country"></div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>



        <div class="name">Name 3</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>
        <div class="country"></div>
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
      </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="second-level" style="display: block;">
        <div class="name">Name 4</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
        
        <div class="name">Name 5</div>
        <div class="status">Some text</div>  
        <div class="country"></div>  
        <div class="country">+000 000 000 000</div>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I need also TEST me under Name 4, how can we do this?

Comment: I can do `nodes[3].textContent  = "TEST ME"`. This isn't the ideal way to do it since you can keep changing the layout etc. Are there any specific name `div` that you want to update ?

Comment: I have to apply a text only to the first item with class `status` in all the li's to be more exact